# Displaying an Image in Google Webpage Index?

Tags: seo, google-search

I have noticed that some sites have an image included on the search listing when googling via a mobile device. To be clear I'm not referring to Google's image index, this is a webpage index that shows the meta description along side an image. It only happens on mobile searches too, not desktop searches.

Having looked at webpages for sites that it's appearing on there doesn't seem to be any logic to it, for example, one site didn't have an og:image tag, so I couldn't put it down to that. One site had a lot of images and the one chosen wasn't the most obvious, i.e. wasn't at the top, wasn't the largest etc. I couldn't see any attributes added to image tags to encourage Google to use it either.

Am I missing something? Is there something I can do to encourage Google to use my logo next to the description text?

Thanks

Comment: Can you do a screenshot of this occurring?

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all

> `<meta property="og:<some_object>" content="<some_content>" />` are for facebook share and the `og:image` is used as featured image of a post shared on facebook
>   [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/)

1. The Search listings with images you are talking about are

> [rich snippet](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-content) or [Carousels](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings)

these are shown by the search engines and for that you need to implement [Structure Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) all the links and images are indexed to search engines and they display them on the basis of quality of content and relevancy with the search